# How can I get clientId of parent encloser in Tapestry 5 component?

Tags: java, components, tapestry

I am developing an ExtJS component model under Taperstry 5. I try to implementy the following API (.tml code):

```
<t:extjs.viewport t:id="ddd" layout="border" width="500">
    <t:extjs.panel t:id="contentBody" title="Content Body" />
</t:extjs.viewport>
```

On the client side I expect to receive the following:

```
Tapestry.onDOMLoaded(function() {
var ddd = Ext.create('Ext.container.Viewport', {
  "id" : "ddd",
  "layout" : "border",
  "width" : 500
});
var contentBody = Ext.create('Ext.panel.Panel', {
  "id" : "contentBody",
  "title" : "Content Body"
});
ddd.add(contentBody);
});
```

In order to write `ddd.add(contentBody);` the child component `contentBody` should know the clientId of the enclosing `ddd` component.

How can I get it? Please advise.

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to inject the direct container of your component with @InjectContainer and obtain its client ID:

```
@InjectContainer
private ClientElement container;

@AfterRender
void addScript() {
    String containerClientId = container.getClientId();
    //pass client ID to JavaScript
}
```